# Terminal Emulator Blinking Words in VIM

Tags: bash, terminal, vim, xterm, words

I am starting to write LaTeX documents in VIM and here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\frac{2x}{2} *
\end{document}
```

For some reason, the following characters are blinking in the terminal:

- {article}
- {document}
- {}{}
- {document}

This forum seems to be related:

https://superuser.com/questions/449335/vi-editor-text-is-flashing-and-unusable/450302

There was another post (EDIT: I found it: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-291190.html) from 2013 saying to do: `export TERM=linux` and I don't want that because text gets bolded and in vifm the selected file blinks.

I just want to turn blinking completely off - I can't see what I am typing when the screen is constantly blinking. It is very distracting.

- OS: Arch Linux
- Terminal emulator: xterm

Comment: What terminal emulator program are you using?

Comment: The emulator being used is xterm